# how to separate and copy csv files from one folder to different folder depending on some condition

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have 3 folders, one for raw files and 2 destination folders. On satisfying the column length of the csv files which are present in the raw folder has to be copied either of the destination folders. once I try the shutil.copyfile (a,des2), it is giving permission denied error.

Comment: Show some code and specific errors. That will help people help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
import shutil
from collections import OrderedDict
path="E:/Test/RawData"
des1="E:/Test/10Length/"
des2="E:/Test/5Length/"
files=os.listdir(path)
col_count_dict=OrderedDict() 
for file in files:
 df=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,file),error_bad_lines=False,sep=",|;|\|",engine='python')
 col_count_dict[file]=len(df.columns)
 if(len(df.columns)==10):
    des = os.path.join(des1, file)
    a=os.path.join(path,file)
    shutil.copy(a,des1)
 elif (len(df.columns)==5): 
    des = os.path.join(des2, file)
    a=os.path.join(path,file)
    shutil.copy(a,des2)
```

I worked on this problem and got it solved. Posting the answer so that it can help someone in saving time.